# Refactoring via Loop a VBA script involving With keyword To reduce Code Length

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In a loop, I have an N by 1 table in PowerPoint slides that as I create them, I format them. I am showing below an example with N=2. How can I refactor this using a loop to reduce the length of the code, please?

```
With pptTable.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignRight
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 54
    .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
End With

With pptTable.Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignRight
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 54
    .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
End With
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a refactor?

Comment: reduce the length of the code.

Comment: @chikitin What will reducing the length of the code accomplish? Assuming that you're only reformatting a few cells, probably nothing, or at least nothing measurable in terms of speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how to split activities up into smaller chunks so that they can be encapsulated in a sub or a function.

```
Sub Test()

    ReformatShape ppttable, 1, 1
    ReformatShape ppttable, 2, 1
    ReformatShape ppttable, 3, 1, ipsize:=48
    ReformatShape ppttable, 4, 1, ipVerticalAnchor:=msoAnchorBottomBaseLine
    ' etc
End Sub


Public Sub ReformatShape _
( _
    ByVal ipTable As PowerPoint.Table, _
    ByVal ipX As Long, _
    ByVal ipY As Long, _
    Optional ByVal ipName As String = "Calibri", _
    Optional ByVal ipAlignment As PpParagraphAlignment = ppAlignRight, _
    Optional ByVal ipsize As Long = 54, _
    Optional ByVal ipVerticalAnchor As MsoVerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle _
)

    With iptable.Table.Cell(ipX,ipY).Shape
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = ipName
        .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ipAlignment
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = ipsize
        .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = ipVerticalAnchor
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this longer than the original?

Comment: If you are setting one or two shapes,, yes otherwise no.